# Is the homebrew warning "We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version." safe to ignore?

Tags: macos, mojave, homebrew

Today I ran `brew upgrade` on my Mojave (10.14.6) setup and was presented the following warning:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.14.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
```

Is this warning safe to ignore and brew will only upgrade to package versions that support my OS version or will it just brute-force upgrade everything and potentially fail?
I have no wish to upgrade from Mojave due to Apple's change in policy after that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn’t ignore it. It’s important - things likely won’t work as expected and you have to do extra diligence on ensuring you get security and stability patches. Same with running an unsupported macOS version but with homebrew, at least the source is open and easier to patch DIY than Apple tools are to tinker with the core OS.

- Does it mean you can’t proceed? No
- Should you think about it, and regularly check your risk level? Yes

Comment: Out-of-scope of the question, but do you know if it's possible to have brew only install known stable versions for my OS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the warning in question is safe to ignore.

Homebrew will only install/upgrade to package version build specifically for your installed OS version.

Comment: Can you provide any source on this claim? It is in complete opposition to the other, higher-voted answer.

Comment: It's safe to ignore, I'm a developer running macos catalina in 2023, using hb regularly I can anecdotally confirm that I havent seen a single broken package

Answer (score -1):

It is not out of support until 30th November. Typical of Homebrew to look to the future.

Comment: What kind of action to you propose if the same message gets displayed on December 1st?

Comment: I agree. Looking forward or establishing boundaries clearly is hardly a blame-worthy trait. I’ve edited the negativity from this post to avoid further flags being raised.